# How to handle animating multiple shapes in Android Canvas?

Tags: kotlin, canvas, android-animation, android-canvas, android-jetpack-compose

**Problem**

I am working with Canvas via Android's Jetpack Compose. I'm trying to draw a bar chart with animations, and it works well after the *first* animation. So whens starting the app, nothing is drawn on screen except the bottom numbers (correct). Then pressing a button changes state and the first bar is drawn to the screen (correct) but it does not animate(incorrect). Afterwards all state changes animate correctly. I'm not sure why.

**Attempts**

I've tried a few things, with my current close-to-working solution being an animation variable per-bar I want to animate. This works, like above, after the first bar is drawn to the screen. The problem is I can't make it animate on the first bar.

**Code Example**

I would like to share all of my code for this. It's for learning, so I figure the better code example available the more likely someone can help and the more help this question will be to others.

```
@Composable
fun RollChart(rolls: Map<Int, Int>, modifier: Modifier) {
    Box(
        modifier = modifier

    ) {

        val animationTargetState = (0..10).map { index ->
            remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        }

        val animationValues = (0..10).map { index ->
            animateFloatAsState(
                targetValue = animationTargetState[index].value,
                animationSpec = tween(durationMillis = 1000),
            )
        }

        Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
            inset(horizontal = 50f, vertical = 48f) {
                val maxRole = rolls.maxOf { it.value }
                val width = (size.width / rolls.size)
                val heightScale = (size.height / maxRole)
                withTransform({
                    translate(left = 50f)
                }) {
                    rolls.forEach { (label, height) ->
                        animationTargetState[label - 2].value =
                            heightScale * height.toFloat()
                        bar(
                            "$label",
                            width,
                            label - 2,
                            animationValues[label - 2].value
                        )
                    }
                }
                val range = IntRange(0, maxRole).step(1 + (maxRole / 5))
                if (range.last == 0) {
                    numberLine("0", 0f)
                }
                for (it in range) {
                    numberLine(
                        "$it",
                        heightScale * it
                    )

                }
            }
        }
    }

}

val textPaint = Paint().asFrameworkPaint().apply {
    isAntiAlias = true
    textSize = 48f
    color = android.graphics.Color.BLACK
    typeface = Typeface.create(Typeface.MONOSPACE, Typeface.BOLD)
}

fun DrawScope.numberLine(
    label: String,
    height: Float
) {
    val base = size.height
    drawLine(
        color = Color.Black,
        start = Offset(0f, base - height),
        end = Offset(size.width, base - height),
        strokeWidth = 5f,
        alpha = 0.5f
    )
    drawIntoCanvas {
        it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
            "$label",
            0f,
            (base - height) - 5f,
            textPaint
        )
    }
}

fun DrawScope.bar(
    label: String,
    width: Float,
    roll: Int,
    height: Float
) {
    val xPos = width * roll.toFloat()
    val base = size.height

    drawRect(
        color = Purple700,
        topLeft = Offset(xPos, base),
        size = Size(width - 10, 0 - height)
    )
    drawIntoCanvas {
        it.nativeCanvas.drawText(
            "$label",
            xPos,
            base + 48f,
            textPaint
        )
    }
}
```

Also I imagine a video demonstration is helpful so I have it here.

[image: Example Gif]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I realized the error was in this line:

```
val heightScale = (size.height / maxRole)
```

The maxRole at the start is 0, which causes the animation to never occur. If anyone can then answer *why* I'd appreciate it, but my thought is that the animation calls are crashing with a number that is impossible. And then after the first render all the maxRole values are > 0.